# Get data into SQL server Management Studio from Accounting Software using ODBC 32bit

Tags: server, odbc, 32-bit, sage50

I have an Accounting Program called Peachtree.  I can get data to MS Access or Excel through the ODBC Driver 32 bits. It is getting harder to have 32 bit applications, I would like to use Office 365 64 bits but I know that 64 bit and 32 bit is not possible to mix. Then, I would like to know if it is possible to get data directly to  SQL server Management Studio using the ODBC 32 Bits Driver.

To get data into SQL Server Management Studio I have to connect the database first to MS Access.  I would like to do it directly